# How do I get Groovy String.replace to remove a substring with unknown digits?

Tags: regex, string, groovy

I have a Groovy String `s` that contains a String variable `name` and follows a pattern like this:

```
name = "{someInformation}"
s = "0/$name|2/{moreInformation}|3/$name"
```

I'm trying to remove \d+/{someInformation}|* (both cases of it) from the string, but this doesn't work because \d+/{someInformation}|* is not the right pattern to match.

The following does not work:

```
s = s.replace ("\\d+/$name|", "")
```

because `s.contains("\\d+/$name|")` returns false.  But I have been fiddling with the regular expression for a while now and I don't seem to be able to get it to match.

What do I need to put into my String.replace regex so that it can find and remove the parts, such that all I have left is

```
s == "2/{moreInformation}"
```

Comment: Not clear. Can you provide some examples of input/output?

Comment: What has `name` got to do with it?

Comment: I'm wondering whether it has something to do with Groovy Strings not being the same as Strings...

Comment: Is `name` value set manaully or is it dynamic?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is dynamic

Comment: No, I want to remove it... :)  I'm using matching to find out what part it's failing on.

Comment: Sorry, got it, but the `|` before the digit should also be removed if present, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes that's right... it should be removed if it's there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex based solution:

```
def name = "{someInformation}"
def s = "0/$name|2/{moreInformation}|3/$name"
println(s) // => 0/{someInformation}|2/{moreInformation}|3/{someInformation} 
// => 0/{someInformation}|2/{moreInformation}|3/{someInformation}
def pat = "\\|*\\d+/${java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(name)}\\|*"
println(pat) // => \|*\d+/\Q{someInformation}\E\|*
println(s.replaceAll(pat, ""))
// => 2/{moreInformation}
```

See the [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/BgSLB4)

Here is the [generated regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/af0XHC/1). Note that `${java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(name)}` is used to escape all special regex metacharacters inside the `name` variable so that they were treated as literal symbols by the regex engine.

**Details**

- `\|*` - 0+ `|` chars
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `/` - a `/` char
- `\Q{someInformation}\E` - a literal `{someInformation}` substring
- `\|*` - 0+ `|` chars

Comment: nice.  I had not heard of Pattern.quote... TIL!  Awesome!  I had been wondering how one escapes those "illegal" characters in a variable.